# How precise does a thermometer measure temperature when wind and sunlight are involved?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, measurements, thermal-conductivity

When driving my car, I often ask myself following question: How does the thermometer measure the air temperature that precisely, and is it even precise?

I know the basic concepts of a thermometer, but let's say the car is sitting in the sun for the whole day. The outside parts of the car are heated up and the thermal energy eventually spreads to all parts of the car, which, even when hidden in "shadow" under the hood, also includes the thermometer at some point. Doesn't this mean the measurement of air temperature would be incorrect? Another scenario would be going 100mph, in which (at least the front of) the car is eventually cooled down by giving of thermal energy to the headwind, again distorting the measurement. I can imagine the thermometer could be isolated from those effect, but in case of perfect isolation, it would not measure anymore, and in case it's not a perfect isolation, the measured temperature would eventually be distorted at some point. Same goes with isolator/conductor combinations, as the conductors have to take the airs' temperature from somewhere and this location has to have "neutral" and unaltered temperature. However, the car's thermometer always shows pretty reliable values (e.g. 20°C), even when standing in the sun for hours or going really fast or even both.

Are the effects I'm describing too miniscule to be visible, is the shown temperature just an approximation or am I missing something completely different?

Depending on the answer, this may lead to a more abstract question:
Is there even something as a spatial air temperature or is it ultimately relative to the specific circumstances of the measuring device and thus, dependent on the very exact location of latter, making every temperature indication an approximation?

Comment: Wind should not be seen as a problem. Wind can only cool down things to the temperature of the air, which is exactly the temperature you would want. So exposing the thermometer to the wind should solve the problems of surfaces being heated by the sun or the engine, at least while driving with enough speed to achieve good "cooling".

Comment: the  thermometer measures the temperature at the place it sits, so if this place is heated by the sun it measures this temperature, Wind plays only a roll if the measuring part of the  thermometer is humid, and this will not exist for longer times,, the wind may blow the higher T from the road surface to your device, depending where it sits.